# Does R have a wildcard expression (such as an asterisk (*))?

Tags: r

I hope I am not missing something obvious but here is my question:

Given data like this

```
Data1=
Name       Number
AndyBullxxx    12
AlexPullxcx    14
AndyPamxvb     56
RickRalldfg    34
AndyPantert    45
SamSaltedf     45
```

I would like to be able to pull out all of the rows starting with "Andy"

```
subset(Data1,Name=="Andy*")

AndyBullxxx  12
AndyPamxvb   56
AndyPantert  45
```

So basically a wild card symbol that will let me subset all rows that begin with a certain character designation.

Comment: Could you mark one of the answers as the correct answer? This gives credits to the answerer and marks this post as correctly answered.

Comment: R is amazing... except for some bits like this one. Stata makes this soooooo easy.

Answer (score 24):

Try,

```
df[grep("^Andy",rownames(df)),]
```

the first argument of `grep` is a pattern, a regular expression. `grep` gives back the rows that contain the pattern given in this first argument. the ^ means beginning with.

Let's make this reproducible:

```
 df <- data.frame(x=c(12,14,56,34,45,45))
 rownames(df) <- c("AndyBullxxx", "AlexPullxcx","AndyPamxvb", "RickRalldfg","AndyPantert","SamSaltedf")
 ## see what grep does
 grep("^Andy",rownames(df))
```

Comment: was untested, tested it now and corrected it to rownames to work with the example. but "\b" is not needed here, just tested on MacOS X UTF-8.

Comment: Good answer.  Just to note - if the case doesn't matter, `ignore.case = TRUE` is a useful argument to `grep`.

Answer (score 12):

If you are not comfortable with `regex` there is a function in the `utils` package, which can convert wildcard based expressions to regex. So you can do

```
df[grepl(glob2rx('Andy*'), rownames(df)),]
```

Comment: +1 good addition to make this answer more comprehensive. Though in this case I guess the regexp is just as easy. Yet it uses the "wildcard" symbol that is intuitive to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to go for a regular expression:

```
subset(Data1, grepl("^\bAndy", Name))
```

or

```
Data1[grepl("^\bAndy", Data1$Name),]
```

In the regular expression the "^" stands for startswith, and \b for the next set of characters is going to be a word. Regular expressions are a powerful text processing tool that require some study. There are a lot of tutorials and websites online. One of them that I use is:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

I can't use R right now (my wifes laptop ;)), so these pieces of code go untested. Maybe next time provide us with an example dataset, that makes it really easy to provide a working example.